# How to detect scroll up or scroll down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Currently I need to listen for a `onWheel` event in react. The event gets triggered. But, I am not able to find a way to detect if user is scrolling up or scrolling down. How shall I detect that event?

```
const handleOnWheel = (event: React.WheelEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      console.log('Scrolling up');
    } else {
      console.log('Scrolling down');
    }
  };
```

This is what I was able to find online. It works well for scroll down. But, for scrolling up, both scroll down and scroll up gets printed to console.

Comment: Have you tried reacting the `scroll` as well? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try running the code below.

```js
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  console.clear();

  if(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY){
    console.log('Scrolling up');
  }
  else{
    console.log('Scrolling down');
  }
  
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be possible, since you either log one message OR the other, which means that `event.deltaY` is rapidly jumping between being `< 0` and *not* being `< 0`. I have tested the exact same code on my computer locally and it was working just fine. There might be a problem with your scroll, maybe it is sending false data due to it being damaged or worn off?

Comment: It's working now. I tried with 
else if(deltaY > 0) instead of just using else.